# Copying values from an Observable to a string array in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have the following variables:

**users: string[];
users$: Observable<string[]>;**

And I want to copy the values from the observable to the string array.

I've tried subscribing and passing the values in **ngOnInit** or in the **constructor** this way:
**this.users$.subscribe(x => this.users = x);**

But the array remains empty. I've already checked if and the observable has the values I need but I want to pass all of them to the array.

Is there a different approach to doing so or am I doing it wrong?
PS(I don't need the observable in the template but I really need the string array to do some logic with it)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question is lacking context and code. Please provide a [mcve] reproducing the issue.

Comment: Maybe you want to create an observable from your string array. Have a look here: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/operators#creation-operators-1. With `of(users)`you can create an observable that will emit the users array when there is a subscription: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/of

Answer (score 0):

I think  you can try like this

`let myobs:Observable<string[]> = of(["test", "test2", "test3"]);`

or like this accordingly

```
ngOnInit() {
  const array=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
  const obsof1=of(array);
  obsof1.subscribe(val => console.log(val),
           error=> console.log("error"),
          () => console.log("complete"))
 
}
```